# Can my insurance company raise my rates for asking them about a claim I may not file?

Tags: united-states, car-insurance

My 16 year old son backed our van into his grandmother's car last night, causing minor damage to one door on her car, though nothing noticeable on our van. I estimate that it will cost a few hundred dollars to fix, likely placing it below our deductible, though I have heard that property damage claims like this may be exempt from deductibles. I would like to discuss this with my insurance agent to decide the most economical way to proceed. However, I am concerned that this discussion may cause them to raise my rates, even if no claim is filed. Can they do this? Would I have any recourse if they did, besides just changing companies?

Comment: Are you sure you're not obliged to tell them about it anyway?

Comment: Might be, I don't know.  That's part of the problem.  Kinda weird to be asking them "So, hypothetically, if we were to have a minor accident--not saying we did--are we obligated to tell you even if we don't file a claim?"

Comment: Read your contract (or call the agent and ask for a copy of it, if you don't have it already)

Comment: I bet they can, just fix it out of pocket.  It really is impossible to know without a bunch more of information.

Comment: Liability claims (that is, when you are liable for damage to another party) are not subject to a deductible.  Deductibles only apply to damage to your own vehicle (collision or comprehensive coverage) where your insurance is paying you; this is intended to shift some burden to you and to keep you from making (many) small claims for minor things.

Comment: @techturtle Not intending to encourage subterfuge, but it wouldn't have to be all that strange to discuss a hypothetical situation with an insurance agent. Once when I bought home owners insurance and saw how their estimates for replacement cost if my house burned down were like 3 times what I paid for the house, I asked the agent, hey, if my house did burn down, could I take the cash, not rebuild the house, buy another comparable house and keep the difference? Perhaps if my house had burned down the next day there would have been some suspicion. :-O

Comment: @Jay Yeah, it's that "the next day" thing that would make it weird, since I would be *hypothetically* asking about an accident, which I then might file a claim for the next day since it had already happened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The estimate we got from the body shop was a lot more than we expected, so we just went ahead and filed a claim.  Since "what happens if we don't file a claim" was no longer an option, I talked with my agent about these questions, so here's what I found.

- Because this was only damage to one car, not ours, it was a liability property damage claim, and therefore no deductible for us.
- I was under no obligation to them to report the claim, though I am responsible for the accident (financially either they or I have to handle it).
- Had I called to discuss possibilities, they would not have adjusted our rates as a result.
- If I start a claim and close it at any time before a payment is made, it will not change our rates.
- There will likely be an increase in my rates, but if and how much will depend on what the repairs cost.

**Nota Bene:** *This is for one insurance carrier, and may even vary from policy to policy, but I think it is likely to be similar with most US insurance companies.*

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer, that's good information.  The last bullet is interesting, though.  I would have thought that your rates were based on the probability of _future_ accidents and that the cost of the prior accident would be irrelevant.  Whether you hit a Bentley or a Yugo, your changes of a future accident are the same. Perhaps they're trying to make up for additional costs that they did not factor into their risk analysis, though.

Comment: @DStanley They presumably have an actuarial figure for the "_expected cost of damages caused by a 16-year-old_" (averaged over Bentleys and Yugos). My guess is in a totally fair world, the premiums should only rise if there is evidence to suggest that _actual_ claims will exceed this expected value... so the value of this claim _could_ play a part, but, I would say, _only_ if there is other evidence that this is not an "expected" claim (e.g. if this was the fourth such claim in as many months; over the "average" of a 16-year-old).